# opencv imshow show gray in Opencv 3.1

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, imshow

Opencv imshow showing gray image.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap;
    Mat frame;
    cap.open(0);
    while (true)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        imshow("test", frame);
        waitKey(30);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I recently upgraded to windows insider preview 14316 and it stopped working after that i think.

I checked if the camera work in skype, and it did. I also tried the code on another computer and it worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: What camera do you have?

Comment: Logitech c310 720p